# How to ignore exceptions while looping?

Tags: python, loops, exception

I am trying to execute a loop while ignoring exceptions. I think `pass` or `continue` will allow me to ignore exceptions in a loop. Where should I put the `pass` or `continue`?

```
class KucoinAPIException(Exception):
    """Exception class to handle general API Exceptions
        `code` values
        `message` format
    """
    def __init__(self, response):
        self.code = ''
        self.message = 'Unknown Error'
        try:
            json_res = response.json()
        except ValueError:
            self.message = response.content
            pass            
        else:
            if 'error' in json_res:
                self.message = json_res['error']
            if 'msg' in json_res:
                self.message = json_res['msg']
            if 'message' in json_res and json_res['message'] != 'No message available':
                self.message += ' - {}'.format(json_res['message'])
            if 'code' in json_res:
                self.code = json_res['code']
            if 'data' in json_res:
                try:
                    self.message += " " + json.dumps(json_res['data'])
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        self.status_code = response.status_code
        self.response = response
        self.request = getattr(response, 'request', None)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'KucoinAPIException {}: {}'.format(self.code, self.message)
```

And this doesn't work:

```
from kucoin.exceptions import KucoinAPIException, KucoinRequestException, KucoinResolutionException

for i in range(10):
    # Do kucoin stuff, which might raise an exception.
    continue
```

Comment: Could you post your stack trace?

Comment: Well, you catch exceptions inside the loop, I guess.

Comment: use try catch in main block where KucoinAPIException is thrown..i.e here  `#do kucoin stuff
    continue`

Comment: thanks all I'm going to try this when I get home.  fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick solution:**

Catching the exceptions *inside* your loop.

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        # Do kucoin stuff, which might raise an exception.
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

**Adopting best practices:**

Note that it is generally considered bad practice to catch all exceptions that inherit from `Exception`. Instead, determine which exceptions might be raised and handle those. In this case, you probably want to handle your `Kucoin` exceptions. (`KucoinAPIException`, `KucoinResolutionException`, and `KucoinRequestException`. In which case your loop should look like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        # Do kucoin stuff, which might raise an exception.
    except (KucoinAPIException, KucoinRequestException, KucoinResolutionException) as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

We can make the except clause less verbose by refactoring your custom exception hierarchy to inherit from a custom exception class. Say, `KucoinException`.

```
class KucoinException(Exception):
    pass

class KucoinAPIException(KucoinException):
    # ...

class KucoinRequestException(KucoinException):
    # ...

class KucoinResolutionException(KucoinException):
    # ...
```

And then your loop would look like this:

```
for i in range(10):
try:
    # Do kucoin stuff, which might raise an exception.
except KucoinException as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

Comment: thank you, this works great!  However, I do have one last question...is there a way to PRINT the error message I would receive and still loop?  I want to know what it is.

Comment: awesome, I'm a newb so I can't upvote until I hit 15...  but when I do will remember you.

Answer (score 1):

`Exception` classes aren't designed to *handle* exceptions.  They shouldn't actually have any logic in them.  Exception classes essentially function like `enums` to allow us to quickly and easily differentiate between different *types* of exceptions.

The logic you have to either raise or ignore an exception should be in your main code flow, not in the exception itself.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was over-complicating things a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can use finally block to execute the block no matter what.

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        #do something
    except:
        #catch exceptions
    finally:
        #do something no matter what
```

Is that is what you were looking for?

Answer (score -2):

use try except in main block where KucoinAPIException is thrown

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
    # do kucoin stuff
    # .
    # .
    # .
    except:
        pass
```

Since you mentioned *ignoring exceptions* I am assuming you would pass all exceptions. So no need to mention individual exceptions at `except:` line.