# Continuing a loop after encountering an error in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, synology

This question is slightly different than other questions about exception handling.

I am trying to set permissions on folders on a Synology NAS using a Python module called SynoACL, which wraps the (otherwise poorly documented) SynoACLTool included on Synology NASes: https://github.com/zub2/synoacl

My code gets a list of all the subdirectories in a directory. The subdirectories are all named after existing users in AD, and I am trying to give them modify rights to the folders that share their names (they are going to be user shares on the network). The script throws an error, but it actually successfully sets the permissions in spite of the error. The problem is that it only does so for the first subdirectory in the directory, and does not continue on to any of the others because of the error. I have tried setting it to ignore all exceptions, but it still fails. Here is my code as well as the error, with personal information removed:

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "synologyusershareperms.py", line 19, in <module>
    SynoACLTool.add(".", SynoACL.fromString(folderPermString))
  File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/synoacl/tool.py", line 406, in add
    return SynoACLTool._parseACLResult(SynoACLTool._communicate(["-add", path, str(acl)]))
  File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/synoacl/tool.py", line 370, in _communicate
    return subprocess.check_output([ SynoACLTool._SYNOACL_CMD ] + args, universal_newlines = True).split("\n")
  File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 711, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['synoacltool', '-add', '.', 'user:DOMAINNAME\\username:allow:rwxpd-aARWc--:fd--']' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

Code:

```
import os
from synoacl.tool import SynoACL, SynoACLTool
user_share_path = '/path/to/share/'
permTemplate1 = "user:DOMAINNAME\\"
permTemplate2 = ":allow:rwxpd-aARWc--:fd--"

os.chdir(user_share_path)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)

folderList = os.listdir()
try:
    for folderName in folderList:
        os.chdir(folderName)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        print(cwd)
        folderPermString = permTemplate1 + folderName + permTemplate2
        print(folderPermString)
        SynoACLTool.add(".", SynoACL.fromString(folderPermString))
        os.chdir("..")
except:
    pass
```

Since adding the try and except lines it doesn't throw any errors anymore, but it stops after the first loop. Is there any way to get it to continue to perform the loop in spite of the error?

Edit: a comment suggested putting the try inside the for loop, doesn't seem to have fixed it:

```
for folderName in folderList:
    try:
        os.chdir(folderName)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        print(cwd)
        folderPermString = permTemplate1 + folderName + permTemplate2
        print(folderPermString)
        SynoACLTool.add(".", SynoACL.fromString(folderPermString))
        os.chdir("..")
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Put the try/except inside the `for` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore exceptions while looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285006/how-to-ignore-exceptions-while-looping)

Answer (score 0):

Put the try/except block inside the for loop:

```
for folderName in folderList:
    try:
        os.chdir(folderName)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        print(cwd)
        folderPermString = permTemplate1 + folderName + permTemplate2
        print(folderPermString)
        SynoACLTool.add(".", SynoACL.fromString(folderPermString))
        os.chdir("..")
    except:
        pass
```

You can also do this (if you don't want to do anything on catching the exception)

```
# contextlib module
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(Exception):
    os.chdir(folderName)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print(cwd)
    folderPermString = permTemplate1 + folderName + permTemplate2
    print(folderPermString)
    SynoACLTool.add(".", SynoACL.fromString(folderPermString))
    os.chdir("..")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to fix it.


The error message makes it sound like it's exiting the script entirely when it errors?  


subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['synoacltool', '-add', '.', 'user:DOMAINNAME\\username:allow:rwxpd-aARWc--:fd--']' returned non-zero exit status 255

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
except:
```

By

```
except Exception as ex:
```

So :

```
import os
from builtins import Exception
user_share_path = '/path/to/share/'
permTemplate1 = "user:DOMAINNAME\\"
permTemplate2 = ":allow:rwxpd-aARWc--:fd--"

os.chdir(user_share_path)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)

folderList = os.listdir()

for folderName in folderList:
   try:
       os.chdir(folderName)
       cwd = os.getcwd()
       print(cwd)
       folderPermString = permTemplate1 + folderName + permTemplate2
       print(folderPermString)
       SynoACLTool.add(".", SynoACL.fromString(folderPermString))
       os.chdir("..")
    except Exception as ex:
      print(ex)
      pass
```